# Magento 2 Get all images of a product, getMediaGalleryImages not work

Tags: magento2, product-images

I have a model, this is the code of getting product collection

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');     
    /** Apply filters here */
    $collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setPageSize($limit) 
        ->setCurPage($page)
        ->load();

    $products = array();
    foreach ($collection as $product){
        $products[$product->getId()]['image_list'] = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    }
```

getMediaGalleryImages() return null, i tried to use $product->getData('image') but only return the url of the main images, anyone know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');     

$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setPageSize($limit) 
        ->setCurPage($page)
        ->load();

$products = array();
foreach ($collection as $product)
{
   $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());
   $products[$product->getId()]['image_list'] = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
}
```